# Would there ever be a need or a way for target nodes in Ansible to communicate with the control node?

Tags: ansible

Ansible control node communicates with the target nodes through ssh. I was wondering - would there ever be a need and a way for the opposite to happen - i.e., the target nodes to communicate with the control node?

Comment: Do you have any particular use-case in mind?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Target nodes to communicate with the control node?"*

A: Sure. See [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html).

Comment: ansible-pull is a wrapper to checkout a playbook and run it on localhost. localhost is the control node;  there is no other host running Ansible.  Of course, you can remote into another other machine, but that's not the typical use case.